# Youtube API - Video Comments Pagination

Tags: php, api, youtube, pagination

I'm using the following PHP code to get the comments for a specific video:

```
<?php
    $vid = "G0k3kHtyoqc";
    $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $vid;
    $entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

    $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
    if($gd->comments->feedLink){ 
        $attrs = $gd->comments->feedLink->attributes();
        $commentsURL = $attrs['href']; 
        $commentsCount = $attrs['countHint']; 
    }

    if($commentsURL && $commentsCount > 0){
      $commentsFeed = simplexml_load_file($commentsURL);    
      echo "<ol>";
      foreach($commentsFeed->entry as $comment){
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.youtube.com/user/" . $comment->author->name . "'>";
        echo $comment->author->name;
        echo "</a>";
        echo " - " . $comment->content;
        echo "</li>";
      }
      echo "</ol>";
    }
?>
```

The problem with the code above is that it only gets the most recent 24 comments. I need a way to paginate through all comments.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the "**start-index**" param. Begins on 1, and depending on the comments count, add [comments-count] to start-index param.

For example: 
First page of comments, getting 25 comments per page, use max-results=25 and start-index=1
Second page of comments, getting 25 comments per page, use max-results=25 and start-index=26

And so on =)

Regards!